How can I make a custom loading in my Nuxt 3 application
I know that Nuxtjs has a built-in component for the loading indicator, but I want to have a custom full page loading spinner
I'm not sure if there is any reserved component like the 404 page that I can create and have it as my loading page.

Like this? https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#spaloadingtemplate
